# $_POST isn't pulling value from the form populated by jQuery.post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've tried researching, but I'm not even sure how to research this question as most of the answers relate to pure jQuery, PHP or HTML, but nobody seems to have the same problem - which probably means I'm missing something blatantly obvious...

I have a form with a select box.  On change of the select box, I call a jQuery.post to a functions page with a php/mysql query and html.  I pull that information back inside my form and it works beautifully.  However, when I post the form, the variable $_POST['subcat'] is empty.  Here is the code:

Form:

```
    <li><h3><?php echo 'Market:';?></h3>
            <script>
                function display_subcat(vals)
                {
                    jQuery.post("<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/?get_subcats_for_me=1", {queryString: ""+vals+""}, function(data){
                        if(data.length >0) {

                            jQuery('#sub_cats').html(data);

                        }
                    });

                }                               
            </script>

        <p><select class="do_input_new" name="market" onchange="display_subcat(this.value)" >
        <option value="">Select Market</option>
        More Options...
        </select>
        <br/><span id="sub_cats">
        </span>

        </p></li>
```

Functions:

```
    if(isset($_GET['get_subcats_for_me']))
    {
        $cat_id = $_POST['queryString'];
        if(empty($cat_id) ) { echo " "; }
        else
        { 

            $args2 = "orderby=name&order=ASC&hide_empty=0&parent=".$cat_id;
            $sub_terms2 = get_terms( 'project_cat', $args2 );   

            if(count($sub_terms2) > 0)
            {

                $ret = '<select class="do_input_new" name="subcat">';
                $ret .= '<option value="">'.__('Select Subcategory','ProjectTheme'). '</option>';

                foreach ( $sub_terms2 as $sub_term2 )
                {
                    $sub_id2 = $sub_term2->term_id; 
                    $ret .= '<option '.($selected == $sub_id2 ? "selected='selected'" : " " ).' value="'.$sub_id2.'">'.$sub_term2->name.'</option>';

                }
                $ret .= "</select>";
                echo $ret;

            }
        }

        die();  
    }
```

Now, when I submit the form, the variable $submarket = $_POST['subcat']; is empty.  Everything else works (the class is what I expect, the data is what I expect), but it seems the name="subcat" isn't coming through to the $_POST.  print_r($_POST) doesn't list subcat.  Thoughts?

Comment: There's no `$submarket` or `$_POST['subcat'];` ?

Comment: By the way, what does `echo 'Market:'` do in `<h3><?php echo 'Market:';?></h3>` ?

Comment: @adeneo that's correct, $_POST['subcat']; comes back empty

Comment: I'm confused, the only thing you're sending is `queryString`, why would `$_POST['subcat']` contain anything ?

Comment: @adeneo I send queryString from the form to functions and then query the database with the queryString value.  Based on the results of the query, I include another select box with the name "subcat" in my form inside the span id="sub_cats".  The values all display correctly in the form (correct class, correct values, etc.).  Am i missing something on needing to pass more values back to the form?

Comment: You're not showing the enclosing `<form>` element, but we'll suppose it does indeed using `POST`. Have you checked what the browser actually sends (using the developer tools, and checking the request sent)? Is the `<span id="sub_cats">` indeed inside the `<form>`? Do you have another element with the same `name`?

Comment: @jcaron the span is inside the <li> in a form : <form method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">.  The value from the "market" posts fine and there are no other elements with the "subcat" name.  I did a print_r of the $_POST and all the other form elements post fine.  "subcat" doesn't exist in the $_POST.  What developer tools do you suggest?

Comment: All modern browsers include developer tools (DOM inspector, console, network traces, etc.). They allow you to see all requests made, along with what data what sent, received, etc. What browser are you using, on what OS?

Comment: @jcaron I'm mostly using chrome on windows 7 64 bit

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-I is your friend. Or menu -> More tools -> Developer tools. Select the Network tab, post your form, check what was actually sent. The Elements tab will also allow you to check that your `select` is indeed seen as within the form and there's no other element with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

I'm an idiot.  The above code worked perfectly.  My problem was that the start of my `<form>` was in a `<div>` that I closed out before the majority of the form.  I suppose since all the other elements were loaded on the same page that they came over in the $_POST, but because "subcat" was new, and after the `<div>` closed, it didn't get picked up in the $_POST.  The form closed long after this particular element, so it must have been because it wasn't original.  Thank you for your help @jcaron!!